# Connections among gigabit switch and 10/100 switch

Tags: windows, networking, switch, kvm-switch

I have a network:

```
server (1GB)--->switch(1GB)--->switch(10/100)---->client(10/100)
```

Is this a proper way to configure a network? What problems might I have if I set it up this way?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the length of the cables do not exceed the maximum allowed lengths, then this configuration should work fine.

Are you experiencing any problems with this configuration ? If so, please describe the problems you are having.

If you need information about cable length limits, please let me know and I will try to provide some info or links.

Kevin

Comment: so, i intends to build my network, but i don't know what problem have i? i wants to know in fact, what problem have it? thanks your help